# Parse byte patterns with variables - Swift

Tags: swift, byte

I am building a VISCA over IP receiver library and need to parse commands from received bytes.

An example of a command is (specifications from [PTZOptics](https://ptzoptics.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/PTZOptics-VISCA-over-IP-Rev-1_2-8-20.pdf) or [Sony](https://www.sony.net/Products/CameraSystem/CA/BRC_X1000_BRC_H800/Technical_Document/C456100121.pdf)):

```
81 01 04 08 2p FF
```

Where `p` is a variable with this meaning: p=0 (Low) - 7 (High)

I need to convert bytes to commands and extract variable values (as `UInt8` can be okay).

At the moment, I have an enum containing commands with custom raw value:

```
import Foundation

public struct RawCommandData: ExpressibleByStringLiteral, Equatable {
    
    init(data: Data) {
        self.byteSequence = [UInt8](data)
    }
    
    public init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        let data = value.hexDataValue!
        
        self.byteSequence = [UInt8](data)
    }
    
    let byteSequence: [UInt8]
}

public enum VISCACommands: RawCommandData {
    case inquiryPTPosition = "81 09 06 12 FF"
    case inquiryZoomPosition = "81 09 04 47 FF"
    case inquiryTally = "81 09 7E 01 0A FF"
    
    init?(from data: Data) {
        let commandData = RawCommandData(data: data)
        self.init(rawValue: commandData)
    }
}

internal extension StringProtocol {
    var hexDataValue: Data? {
        let stringNoSpaces = self.components(separatedBy: .whitespaces).joined()
        guard stringNoSpaces.count % 2 == 0 else { return nil }
        var data = Data()
        var byteLiteral = ""
        for (index, character) in stringNoSpaces.enumerated() {
            if index % 2 == 0 {
                byteLiteral = String(character)
            } else {
                byteLiteral.append(character)
                guard let byte = UInt8(byteLiteral, radix: 16) else { return nil }
                data.append(byte)
            }
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

So I can parse commands in this way:

```
let receivedBytes = "81 09 06 12 FF".hexDataValue!
let command = VISCACommands(from: receivedBytes)
```

This solution doesn’t work for commands containing variables.

Is there any efficient way to lookup for a match between a sequence of bytes (the command received) and a pattern of bytes that can contain a variable? I think of something like RegEx, that allows extracting variables.